# Run multiprocessing from a thread

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

Can I run multiprocessing from a thread?. I ask because I have tried, and, it works inside Spyder, however, it does weird things when the EXE file is created.

Weird things like opening multiple GUI's. Here is a relevant piece of code:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    #class to handle GUI
    #at some point does this
    def startWorker(self):
        self.worker1= WorkerThread()
        self.worker1.start()

class WorkerThread(QtCore.QThread):
     #class to do long hard work without freezing GUI
     def __init__(self, parent=None):
         QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)
         super(WorkerThread, self).__init__(parent)

     def run(self):
         p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=someTraget, args=someArgs)
         p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=someTarget, args=someArgs)
         p1.daemon = True; p2.daemon = True
         p1.start();p2.start()
```

**EDIT: to a comment:**

To create the EXE file I am using PyInstaller 2.1 like this:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed main.py
```

And the calling to my main looks like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    multiprocessing.freeze_support()

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.showMaximized()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: 'opening multiple GUI's' - would that not be normal behaviour if you start multiple processes?

Comment: As far as I understand the situation, I am calling multiprocesses from the "worker" thread class, which (as far as I understand) has nothing to do with the Main class....so, if I did it correctly (I think so), the main class is called just once, at the beginning...please correct me if I a wrong, thanks!

Comment: Are you protecting the entry point of your program with an `if __name__ == "__main__":` guard? Also, if you're using something to turn the script into a .exe, are you calling `multiprocessing.freeze_support()` at the start of the program? Leaving out either of those could cause the issue you described.

Comment: Yes I have done both of those, I think the seccond one comes from an issue with multiprocessing and PyInstalled. I edit my question with this data. Thanks!

Comment: eddie, have you ever solved this? I too would like to make a multiprocessing call to a C-function from a 2nd thread. Does it work?

Comment: @Cat have you made this worked? I want the same thing. Thanks